# How do I target any other device than Android, iPhone or iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a functionality where I need to specify an url on an anchor for Android, iPhone or iPad, but when there is another device, I have to set another default url.

See my code:

```
var isiPhone = /iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var isiPad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var isAndroid = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var isMobile = false;

var setMobileDevice = function() {
    if (isiPhone || isiPad || isAndroid) {
        isMobile = true;
    } else {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 643) { // For any other devices not registered in the variables above.
            $('.mobile-getapp--link').attr('href', 'default-url');
        }
    }
};

var assignURL = function () {
    if (isiPhone) {
        $('body').addClass('iPhone');
        $('.mobile-getapp--link').attr('href', 'url-for-iPhone');
    }

    if (isiPad) {
        $('body').addClass('iPad');
        $('.mobile-getapp--link').attr('href', 'url-for-iPad');
    }

    if (isAndroid) {
        $('body').addClass('android');
        $('.mobile-getapp--link').attr('href', 'url-for-Android');
    }
};

setMobileDevice();
if (isMobile) {
    assignURL();
}
```

All I want is to know if is I am missing something where I am not targeting the other devices to get the default url

Comment: Why not use switch case?

Comment: @BhushanBabar because aren't too many cases. At the end will be the same.